# Is it possible to update pagelayout after upload a file using sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Hi I uploaded a file using sharepoint rest api using below url

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Pages')/files/add(url='Pages/14789564.aspx')
```

If you see in below screenshot Page Layout created as empty. Is it possible to update or create pagelayout here

Can any one help me onthis

[image]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830552/how-to-set-page-layout-of-list-item-in-sharepoint-rest

Comment: Am using sharepoint online. Is there any way to create a page with page layout using rest api? as of now am trying to create a page by uploading a document of .aspx and then trying to update fields of page. but couldn't succeeded to update page layout as its read only field as per link given by you

Comment: Not sure if it is possible using REST API. You might be able to do it using JSOM or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Content Type ID associated with this page layout. In Master Page gallery you can see what the layout associate with this page layout.